# C++ Output to file using fstream ignored

Tags: c++

So here's the issue, i'm trying to save an integer to a file and while it has worked before it suddenly stopped working at one point and i'm trying to figure out what caused that to happen.

The line in question is `count << counter;` within the following code:

```
int main()
{

//variable declarations, opens countFile with cursor at end of file
fstream count("countFile.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);
int counter = 0, size;

//checks if file opened successfully
if (!count.is_open())
{
    cout << "\tError cannot open file!\n\n";
    return 1;
}

//goes to end of count file
count.ignore((numeric_limits<streamsize>::max)());

//finds number of characters in the file and saves it into size
size = count.gcount();

//resets eof flag on count file stream
count.clear();

//returns cursor to beginig of file
count.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

//checks if file size is 0
if (size != 0)
{
    //inputs value from file into position 0
    count >> counter;
    //loads previous state
    load(counter);
}



//runs menu function
counter = menu(counter);

//Test contents of counter
cout << counter;

//overwrites data in countFile
count << counter;

//saves table
save(counter);

return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: You opened the file with `ios::in | ios::binary`. You're missing an `ios::out` here.

Comment: Thank you, i can't believe i missed that @Quentin

Comment: Right, it works when the file is empty but when it comes to overwriting value that was originally there it doesn't do that, any ideas as to how to make it do it?

Comment: Whenever you go from reading to writing (or vice versa) you have to do a seek to set the file position. An fstream only has one "current position" and as soon as you do a read it will become the "read position" and then there is no "write position" (and vice versa).

Comment: so to fix that i'd have to close the file and reopen it or is there a better way of getting from a read position to a write position? @BoPersson

Comment: You already use `seekg` to set the read position. You can use `seekp` to set the write position. But you have to do this each time you "switch direction".

Comment: Great thank you for the help! @BoPersson

Comment: Don't use *formatted* output operator with binary files; use `fstream::write` instead.  Likewise, use `fstream::read()` instead of `operator>>`.

Comment: is there a particular reason for that? @ThomasMatthews

Comment: @ilkam:  A textual (formatted) representation will require a minimum of one byte per digit or character in the floating point.  The binary representation can take 4 bytes (32-bit floating point) or 8 bytes (64-bit floating point).  The `write` function will copy the data from memory without converting to human readable form.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @ThomasMatthews